# IPython - have print default to print head & tail on long variables

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython

(For working in IPython only, either terminal or QTConsole, not Notebook) Is there a way to make a regular print statement (yes, 2.7) automatically print the head and tail (or even just the head) of a variable if it is over some arbitrary size?

If I `print dataframe` on a pandas dataframe that is too big, pandas automatically just prints the head.  I'd like it work that way on lists and numpy arrays too, so that the next time I accidentally print a giant array out by accident I don't wind up with 100 pages of numbers.  (I'm sure I could write a function to do this, but I reflexively use print, so I'm wondering if there's a way to control how much IPython will display - really, I'd rather change what the console displays instead of what the program is doing.)

Comment: I agree about lists/dictionaries, but I think numpy arrays automatically limit how much is printed. (If you realize that you've accidentally typed `print longList` and the screens of data are flashing you by, you can usually ctrl-c out of it)

Comment: It's kind of a fundamental thing in python that the `__str__` method is part of each individual class (and not centrally), which is to say, I don't *think* this is going to be possible in general... but happy to learn otherwise!

Comment: Printing a NumPy array produces a summary if the array has more than 1000 elements. This is configurable with [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Comment: IPython overwrites `sys.displayhook()` with their own custom version.  You can probably subclass [`IPython.core.displayhook`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.displayhook.html) with you customised version and assign it to `sys.displayhook` in some IPython initialisation file.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: `sys.displayhook` doesn't trigger for `print` statements, though.

Comment: @user2357112: True.  Just don't print stuff, enter `a` instead of `print a`.

Comment: To limit the number of listed items per dimension per array printed, use `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=20)` for numpy arrays, and `pandas.set_option()` for pandas output, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#working-with-package-options)

Comment: OK, I can put the numpy.set_printoptions() in my startup script, is there anything similar that can be done for lists?  @user2357112 - didn't notice this, because I tried `print np.array(1000)`.  It must have been a 70k item list then that provoked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do much with `print` statement, but you can do something about `ipython`'s output, consider these to commands:

```
In [13]: x = range(3)

In [14]: x
Out[14]: [0, 1, 2]

In [15]: print x
[0, 1, 2]
```

First, `x` assigns `Out[14]` to value of the expression and that `Out[14]` is then displayed.

You can hack `ipython` to display it differently. From what I can tell, `ipython` uses `pprint` internally or a copy thereof. Simply monkey-patching `pprint.pprint/pprint.pformat/pprint.PrettyPrinter` doesn't work though. You'd need to hack ipython proper.

Second, `print x` goes straight to the heart of Python. In python 2.x you cannot change what `print` does. In python 3.x `print()` is just a function and you can monkey-patch it.

If what you print is a object of your own class, feel free to redefine `__str__` and `__repr__` like numpy does:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=2)
numpy.array(range(10)).__str__()
'[0 1 2 ..., 7 8 9]'
print numpy.array(range(10))
[0 1 2 ..., 7 8 9]
```

Finally, `ipython` comes with `%page` magic command, you can issue `%page x` and if representation of `x` is large enough, you'll be dropped to `less` or similar pager where you can view this text representation one page at a time.

P.S. `ipython` is extensible via "traits," it's still back magic for me, but perhaps you can solve first case using traits.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like I can't do exactly what I want, but this is an extremely helpful explanation of what is possible and what IPython is doing below the surface that's different from a standard Python console.